# Please dsescribe how this instrument works

Tags: radio-telescope

Describe how this instrument works:

[image]

Comment: Yeah you didn't put in too much work into this, did you?

Comment: If you want useful answers, please start by doing a little bit of research on your own. You might as well have asked "what is the Earth made of?"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can you give me a basic rundown of what how this works?

Comment: @UltraGamer You ignored him and just repeated your question. Again, we'd appreciate if you did some research before posting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the Very Large Array.  The very large array is a Y shaped array of massive Radio astronomy observatory. It has the computing power to function as an interferometer.  Each radio is mounted on double parallel railroad tracks, so the radius and density of the array can be transformed to adjust the balance between its angular resolution and its surface brightness sensitivity.  If you want to read more, read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Array).